# About speaking --N-- words between African Americans

Tags: usage, slang, offensive-language

I enjoy watching the **[Kee & Peele](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EtalOOS-eM)**. As you can hear around 2:00～, from this sketch, Troy and Mark are beginning to "exchange their words". Now they are saying, for example, Troy says to Mark "What the fuck do you think you are doing, nigger?", in response to it, Mark says "I'm doing my thing, nigger."

Now the question is, when African American people use these N words, which were once thought to be quite offensive, I think, does this imply voicelessly
**they belong to same groups**? ( Although they are almost about to fight now ).

I appreciate answers and let me thank you in advance.

Comment: I am sorry it was **N** words......

Comment: I guess it all depends on the tone and on the situation. Sometimes the main message would be to "highlight the racial bond" between two persons, while in other situations the main purpose would be to cause offense, even if both persons are black. Sometimes it would be just a convivial, jocular way to greet another black guy. There are no etiquette rules for using the N word among (between) black people, I believe, so it will always be a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer/comment. I kind of thought like you but they are as you say using the N words so often according to the situation and I am glad you helped me out about this. Thank you so much for your good comment. Sincerely.

Comment: @CopperKettle, that's a good answer. Why not actually make it one instead of a comment? (I was tempted to do so myself, but I don't want to steal the points that are likely to result.)

Comment: @tkp - voila! (0:

Comment: ahm..why did this go to on-hold? The 2 people in the video are **actually speaking** and they are being broadcast in your country.....

Comment: It  is not n words with an s. It is the n word without an s. I think one has to be very careful here if one is white. Black Americans are not a homogeneous group. Frankly, I have never seen one black person use it offensively towards another. ***I have heard it used as a replacement for guy between two young black men. So I heartily disagree the @CowperKettle.*** There are tons of sites on the internet that discuss this better than we could here. The term was revived as ok by young black rappers or street talking, for example. In other circles, it is mostly frowned upon.

Comment: The term is still offensive unless used by young black American men who are peers, among themselves. Many older black Americans would be very offended by it and it is a term revived in a certain street culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it all depends on the tone and on the situation. Sometimes the main message would be to "highlight the racial bond" between two persons, while in other situations the main purpose would be to cause offense, even if both persons are black. Sometimes it would be just a convivial, jocular way to greet another black guy. There are no etiquette rules for using the N word among (between) black people, I believe, so it will always be a bit ambiguous.

Comment: This answer is off base, full of assumptions and it is a disservice to the OP to make those claims. First off, only young men use it, not older African Americans who probably would not ever use it. You miss the main point about **young black men** and only in some sociological situations and the fact the term was "taken back" just like "queer" in LBTGQ communities.